# How to persist changes to boot2docker in docker-machine?

Tags: linux, docker, docker-machine

I am using docker-machine which I use to manage VM running boot2docker with virtualbox as  driver. I need to mount directory to this VM. I was able to do that by adding the folder to shared folders list in settings of VM in Virtualbox Manager. Then using `sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=1000,gid=50 <name of folder in VM settings> <folder name>`. It worked & I added the command to create directory & mount without using relative address to `etc/rc.local` . The changes I made to VM don't persist when I restart the VM. What do I do?

I am working on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Persist across what?

Comment: try https://github.com/SvenDowideit/boot2docker/blob/f37e262961a870c2c6876c63da4f409595bb2243/README.md#folder-sharing

Comment: @NathanielWaisbrot Persist in the VM running boot2docker

Answer (score 1):

The persistent directories are documented here: https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/master/doc/FAQ.md#local-customisation-with-persistent-partition

So you can add your `mount` command to `bootlocal.sh` under `/var/lib/boot2docker/` directory.

Answer (score -2):

Create a folder. Inside, create a `Dockerfile`. The first line should be `FROM` plus the name of the image which you currently use.

Then you can add the commands to modify the base image. In your case, put a copy of `rc.local` in the same folder as the `Dockerfile`

Now you can copy it into your new image with:

```
ADD rc.local /etc
```

You can then build your new image with `docker build -t user1932582/myapp .`

That creates a new image which you can run with `docker run user1932582/myapp`

Related:

- http://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/